# Bluetooth peripheral v. central energy usage

Tags: iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, battery, energy

Does a a device, say an iphone, require more energy to advertise as a BLE peripheral in the background than it would if it were scanning as a BLE central in the background? If so then by how much? Again I am refering to a small device such as an iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core bluetooth is optimized for minimal power consumption. There is practically no difference between the central and peripheral roles. Don't worry about the power consumption of ble operations, the Apple engineers have taken care of that for us.  You should be more concerned with writing your critical business logic to run efficiently.